# Как передать аргумент из команды в кнопку disnake?

Tags: disnake

Я пишу код для выдачи выговоров, как передать аргумент из команды в кнопку

```css
class Staff(disnake.ui.View):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(timeout=None)
    self.value = Optional[bool]

  @disnake.ui.button(label="Выдать выговор", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple, emoji="❕")
  async def help(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.CommandInteraction, пользователь: disnake.Member):
    guild = client.get_guild(1170102476607852674)
    channel = guild.get_channel(1170358731427549214)
    await channel.send(embed=disnake.Embed(title="❕Устный выговор", description=f"{пользователь} получает выговор\nАдминистратор: {inter.author}"))

@commands.has_any_role(1170103739101753504)
@client.slash_command(name="manage-staff", description="Управление персоналом")
async def staff(self, inter: disnake.CommandInteraction):
  view = Staff()
  await inter.response.send_message(view=view)
```